# How to know if a stored procedure is executed from other stored procedures?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have done some changes in a stored procedure(Say A) and in my project there are more than 500 stored procedures.

There can be stored procedures which are executing my stored procedure **A** within them.

Now I need to know, which other stored procedures are going to get affected with my change?

**I mean**: How to know stored procedure **A** is called from which other stored procedures? Is it possible?

Comment: You'll need to look at the definitions of your other SPs. You could use something like [SQL Search](https://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-search/) to do this, or you could use the `sys.sql_modules` and `sys.procedures` objects with as `LIKE` statements against the `definition` column.

Comment: You can generally look in the system tables.  **However** stored procedures can execute dynamic SQL -- and these calls are not captured in the metadata.  For this reason, I like to have an audit trail of what actually happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find them using:

```
SELECT  P.name
,       SM.definition
FROM    sys.procedures AS P
INNER JOIN sys.sql_modules AS SM
        ON SM.object_id = P.object_id
WHERE   SM.definition LIKE '%ProcedureA%'
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few methods to find dependencies. So, inn order of preference...

### Database Projects

If you're not already working with these; you really should be.

Here's a place to start your adventure, young Padawan: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/data-tools/creating-and-managing-databases-and-data-tier-applications-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019

### Dependency Checker in SSMS

In short; right-click the object in the Object Explorer pane in SQL Server Management Studio and chose "Show dependencies..."

Example on this answer, here: [Microsoft SQL Server foreign key dependencies show up using sp_MSdependencies but are not listed in sys.foreign_keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53675738/microsoft-sql-server-foreign-key-dependencies-show-up-using-sp-msdependencies-bu)

### Some SQL!

e.g. `sys.sql_expression_dependencies`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-sql-expression-dependencies-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query to search procedures which call yours.

```
select
    p.name
    , m.definition
from sys.procedures p
    inner join sys.sql_modules m
        on p.object_id = m.object_id
where n.[name] <> 'procedure_name'
    and m.definition like '%procedure_name%'
```

Essentially, you are looking through stored procedure definition and looking for the name / text of your stored procedure.

Comment: Thanks for the downvote, but why? What is wrong with my answer?

Comment: Hey @Radu, I didn't downvoted your answer, somebody else did. I gave you +1. I found all three answers helpful and i gave +1 to all of them. Thanks.